# Where is the assertion error coming from? I've been testing this code several times and it keeps failing each time. Don't know where the problem is

Tags: assertion

I've been trying to test this code and it keeps failing. I tried rewriting the code structure multiple times and it's not working. Also, I've tried to understand the error message it's giving me but to no avail. I'd appreciate if someone could fully explain to me what the error message means and also help me better understand how assertion works since I'm a beginner in python.

## This is the code:

`

```
from city_functions_pop import formatted_city_country

def test_city_country():
    """Do the places 'accra', 'ghana' work?"""
    formatted_name_of_place = formatted_city_country('accra', 'ghana')
    assert formatted_name_of_place == 'Accra, Ghana'

def test_city_country_population():
    """Verifiy calling of functions with certain values."""
    formatted_name_of_place = formatted_city_country('santiago', 'chile', population=5000000)
    assert formatted_name_of_place == 'Santiago, Chile- population 5000000'

`
```

## And this is the result:

PS C:\Users\ibrah\OneDrive\Desktop\python_work> python -m pytest
========================================================== test session starts ===========================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.11.3, pytest-7.4.1, pluggy-1.3.0
rootdir: C:\Users\ibrah\OneDrive\Desktop\python_work
collected 4 items

chapter_11\test_cities.py .F                                                                                                        [ 50%]
chapter_11\test_name_function.py ..                                                                                                 [100%]

================================================================ FAILURES ================================================================
E         - Santiago, Chile- population 5000000
E         + <built-in method title of str object at 0x0000016C5ECF86F0>, Chile-population 5000000

chapter_11\test_cities.py:13: AssertionError
======================================================== short test summary info =========================================================
FAILED chapter_11/test_cities.py::test_city_country_population - AssertionError: assert '<built-in me...ation 5000000' == 'Santiago, Ch...ation 5000000'
====================================================== 1 failed, 3 passed in 0.15s =======================================================
PS C:\Users\ibrah\OneDrive\Desktop\python_work>

I believe the error is related to the population value.